# How can I transfer files from Android to Ubuntu (and vice versa)?

Tags: usb, android, mtp

I've a phone (Huawei Mate 20 Lite) which runs Android (version 10) and I would like to transfer some songs, movies, documents, etc to my phone but I don't know the best way to do this.

I've done some research online but I've only found old ways that are no longer valid.

I'm currently using KDEconnect but this isn't (for me) the best way to transfer my stuff, as I have to establish the connection each time I want to transfer something, and it's a bit slow while transferring.

I wonder if it's possible to transfer files to an Android phone from Ubuntu desktop through USB connection.

I've also installed `mtp-tools`, but when I switch my phone to MTP and try to run the `mtp-detect` command, it doesn't detect anything.

What do you advise me?

(I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS).

Thanks!

Comment: does it have to be the best way or is it fine if it simply works? every thing you need to transfer files via usb are pre installed in ubuntu and in andoid.all you need to do is to plug in the cable and okay the transfer of files via usb.

Comment: have you tried simply connecting the phone and using the file manager to manage your files between devices?

Comment: An alternative: use google drive to sync between phone and Ubuntu.

Comment: Using "MTP alternative USB Drive " app on your android phone along Dolphin file manager you can do it easily. here is how  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zs6woLcV3OA

Answer (score 11):

I think, wired is always better than wireless.

Just plug in your phone to the PC via USB cable. And then on the phone you will get a prompt saying `Allow access to phone data?`, or something similar to this (depending on the brand and model). Click `allow` or something similar to this (depending on the brand and model).

In file manager, your phone will be visible in the side tab. Alternately, it will also be visible in the favorites bar. Just click any of those and you are good to go.

I have attached a screenshot showing both the locations.

[image]

Comment: I've always found this method to be unreliable, especially in a folder with a large number of files.

Comment: @rtaft this is the most reliable method as far as I know. I have used Ubuntu and android for more than 2 years now, never have I ever experienced any problem. Might be a problem with your drivers.

Comment: Then the quality of the cable and the connector tends to be an issue. Touching the cable is easily done and it tends to interfere. My experience is the same: cable works best for me. Do I also do use wireless and bluetooth also where BT is annoying.

Comment: @Abhay Patil It works fine with a Note 10, but it rarely worked right with the Galaxy S5 and S3, this is with Ubutnu 18.

Comment: Just gives me an empty Samsung folder

Comment: @JamesHirschorn you also need to grant the permission to access the storage from mobile phone

Answer (score 7):

Try https://snapdrop.net/

Instructions to use snapdrop:

1. Open https://www.snapdrop.net both in your PC and your smartphone. (Make sure that both the devices are connected to the same network.)
2. The smartphone and the PC will be given a name by the website.
   In my case, my PC is named as *Coral Ferret* and my smartphone is named as *Gold Spoonbill*.

   [image: Screenshot of https://www.snapdrop.net in Firefox in PC]

   [image: Screenshot of https://www.snapdrop.net in Chrome in smartphone]
3. If I want to share a file from my PC to smartphone, I must click on *Gold Spoonbill* option in my PC. Then choose the files which needs to be shared.
4. Then on your phone, you will get an option to download the file.
5. Download the file. And that's it!

The steps will be similar even if you transfer files from smartphone to PC.

---

This might not be the best method (since *best* is subjective), but it's one of the easiest methods.

Comment: AFAICT doesn't this ultimately use the internet to transfer files? If so, why not just use Google Drive (since we're in the Google ecosystem already), which presumably has drag-and-drop as well.

Comment: @MarsAndBack Well, in the case of Google Drive, one has to have a Google account right? Whereas in the method which I've mentioned, there's no need for any account :)

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way to transfer files between the phone and a PC is to use a MicroSD card, especially if you keep all of your files on the MicroSD card anyway.

Comment: before down voting without giving a reason, understand that when this was answered, MicroSD cards were standard on smart phones and using MTP was often unreliable.  This is not as much the case today.